# Фильтр выдачи logCat AndroidStudio

Tags: android, регулярные-выражения, eclipse, android-studio, logcat

В **Eclipse** пользовал фильтр вида

> tag:^(?!TelephonyManager) tag:^(?!charger_monitor) tag:^(?!WeatherReflect) ТУТ_ЕЩЁ_ОЧЕНЬ_МНОГО_ТЕГОВ

коий просто копипастил в поле фильтра, убирая тем самым лишнюю инфу.

В **AndroidStudio** же нашёл только такой интерфейс для добавления фильтров:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понял, он подразумевает создание фильтра только по одному тегу за раз.

**Засим вопрос**: как мне с минимальным трудом применить мой длинный фильтр из **Eclipse** к logCat **AndroidStudio**?

Comment: Здесь фильтр по тегу - выражение regex. Оно может быть сколько угодно сложным.

Comment: да, можно использовать регулярку и вы выловите все что угодно

Comment: Да, выяснилось, что надо просто все мои теги объединить в одно выражение) Почему-то я забыл это чуть прогуглить... 0_о

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14609392/3212712), строку подходящую в **Eclipse**

> tag:^(?!TelephonyManager) tag:^(?!charger_monitor) tag:^(?!WeatherReflect)

для **AS** надо преобразовать к виду

> ^(?!TelephonyManager|charger_monitor|WeatherReflect)

и поместить в поле **Log Tag (regex)** диалога со скриншота из вопроса.

---

Вот этот простой метод преобразует фильтр из Eclipse в фильтр для AS:

```
private static String makeLogCatFilter(String eclipseFilter)
{
    String ASFilter;
    //eclipse filter
    //tag:^(?!TelephonyManager) tag:^(?!charger_monitor) tag:^(?!WeatherReflect)
    //Android Studio filter
    //^(?!TelephonyManager|charger_monitor|WeatherReflect)
    ASFilter = eclipseFilter.replaceFirst("tag:", "");
    ASFilter = ASFilter.replace(") tag:^(?!", "|");
    return ASFilter;
}
```